# c# .net fastJSON complex JSON string to Object

Tags: c#, .net, json, fastjson

EDIT: Updated JSON string to valid JSON
I am trying to convert a JSON string to preferably a class in c# using fastJSON.

This is my string (I cut everything out so only thing left is what I have trouble with)

```
{
"apps": {
    "App Name 1": {
        "label": "AppNam1",
        "versions": [
            {
                "app_version": "4.7",
                "application": "appname1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "App Name 2": {
        "label": "App Name 2",
        "versions": [
            {
                "app_version": "1.0",
                "application": "appname2"
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, using fastJSON I am trying to convert this to the following model:

```
[Serializable()]
public class AppsRoot
{
    public List<AppDetail> apps;
}

[Serializable()]
public class AppDetail{    
    public string label;
    public List<AppVersions> versions;
}
```

However, this does not work for a couple reasons (at least, that's why I think it is not working):
- First of all, the apps : {} contains a list of apps. However, fastJSON does not see this as a list. Probably because there have to be brackets around it in order to be a list? (like it is for versions)
- Secondly, the AppName1 and AppName2 are dynamic keys. How can I make fastJSON assign this to an attribute somehow, if that is even possible?

This is the code I execute:

```
fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<AppsRoot>(myjsonstring)
```

It just returns an empty AppsRoot object.

FYI: if I just take the JSON for a single App containing a label and do this:

```
fastJSON.JSON.ToObject<AppDetail>(myjsonstring-part)
```

Then it does work. I returns the AppDetail with a list of versions.

Hopefully someone can help me out. The reason I am using fastJSON is because of performance btw, but I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Try making your list into a dictionary instead, because that is what that level of the json is.

Comment: I'm not sure your JSON is valid. It looks like you have a property called 'apps' that is a class, but then there's a comma and another class and these aren't encapsulated with square brackets. 

Second, your classes in your list have a different property name for their app name ('AppName1' and 'AppName2') Since you edited the JSON, maybe this is not the way it actually looks, but currently the JSON structure looks like your problem.

Comment: The json is not valid, before asking for help on "how do I parse my json", ensure your json is valid. Visit [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and get your json valid first.

Comment: Thanks guys. I already expected the JSON to be invalid, but this JSON is what I get from a large company so I assumed it would be OK. This is actually how I receive this, and that's appearantly the problem.. Thanks

Comment: So, the JSON was actually invalid due to my simplification of the original JSON string. However, I revalidated it and fixed the issue. I have now updated my question with the actual (valid) string.

I guess the issue is that App Name 1 and App Name 2 are dynamic? I am looking for some way to map those to a generic c# object (like map the keys App Name 1 and App Name 2 to a field called 'dynamickey'. But I don't know if that's even possible.